# value of input type time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
<input required="" id="time" type="time">
```

js:

```
var time = $('#time').val();
console.log(time); // it outputs e.g. 10:00
var newTime = time--; // NaN
var convert = new Date(time); // Invalid Date
```

How to work with the value of input? I want to compare it to the other input's value or other basic operations like decrease time with 1 hour but I'm not able to convert it to Date object.

Comment: It's just a string http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_input_time_value.asp

Comment: `document.querySelector("#time").valueAsDate` or `.valueAsNumber` -> [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement)

Comment: I know, but question is how to convert it to date? edit: thanks

Comment: is there any way how to get that value in jquery(with $(this))? $(this).valueAsDate doesn't work

Comment: @dontHaveName _"is there any way how to get that value in jquery(with $(this))? $(this).valueAsDate doesn't work"_ `valueAsDate` is `DOM` element proerty , not jQuery method . See post.

Comment: I know it's not jquery method. And yes I see now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `valueAsDate` property

```js
$("input[type=time]").on("change", function() {
  console.log(this.valueAsDate)
})
```

```html
<input required="" id="time" type="time">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and any way how to get it back to hh:mm? just with new Date(value) right?

Comment: @dontHaveName _"any way how to get it back to hh:mm?"_ Try `this.valueAsDate.toJSON().slice(-13, -8)` . Could also use `this.valueAsDate.getHours()` , `this.valueAsDate.getMinutes()`